# mysql SELECT with more than 1 OR's

Tags: mysql, sql, select, operator-precedence

I am trying to make a numrows query to see if the user is friends with the other user, by doing user1 and user2.

Here is my query, but this doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM friends 
WHERE friend1 = USER_ID
AND friend2 = FRIEND
OR
WHERE friend1 = FRIEND
AND friend2 = USER_ID
```

So the query is checking to see it in both ways, back to front, how do I make this possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only have one `WHERE` in a SQL statement, so you would want to use something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM friends 
WHERE 
(
  friend1 = USER_ID
  AND friend2 = FRIEND
) 
OR
(
  friend1 = FRIEND
  AND friend2 = USER_ID
)
```

The parentheses are not required due to operator precedence, I used them for clarity.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try it with parenthesis?

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (friend1 = USER_ID AND friend2 = FRIEND) OR (WHERE friend1 = FRIEND AND friend2 = USER_ID)
```